# Find all occurrences of assignment operator (=) for specific type in Visual Studio (in C#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm changing some `struct T { ... }` in my code to `class T { ... }` while mainlining the logic of the code. So I'm traveling the code and searching method calls that changes `T` members and other things that can "break" the code.

The hardest thing to find is all the places that using assignment operators on this `T` (assignment was value-duplication, and now it's reference-duplication).

There are many lines of code and I'm trying to find fast way to locate those assignments.

- The obvious way is to do `Shift + F12` in VS - but it doesn't work.
- Other way - overriding `=` operator - is not possible in C#.
- I saw similar question about `==` ([find all occurrences of comparison with == in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587242/find-all-occurrences-of-comparison-with-in-visual-studio)) but their solution can't be applied in my case.
- If there is way to make `T` references un-assignable, it'll raise error in each assignment, but I don't now how it can be done.

How can I find those assignments? I need it **before** run-time, as built-in feature of VS or by some trick of compile-time etc.

Comment: If you have Resharper, you can do this easily, using the "Find usage" command. Results can be filtered to find assignments.

Comment: Is it just assigning from `class T` to `class T` that you want to find, or are there more complex instances, such as derived classes, or assignment to/from other types?

Comment: @ClickRick: It's just `T` to `T`.

Comment: @Benlitz: Thanks! It's possible solution, if I won't find something better.

Comment: @Y.Shoham That's a shame. The more complex instances would have been simpler to find. Good luck with Resharper!

Answer (score 1):

Mark all the members with the obsolete attribute and recompile, you should get a warning on every line that tries to access (read or write) that property / method.

It includes more than you'd like (readers too) but that's a starting point that should be enough unless your project is massive. If it is you will probably want to look into roslyn and parse your whole project.